# Disable onbeforeunload for submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit, onbeforeunload

I have javascript code which alerts users before refreshing the page:

```
<head>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return true;
};

$('#quizsb_f').submit(function() {
   $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});

</script>
</head>
```

But it is also alerting when a user clicks on the submit button of the page.

**I don't want to show any alerts on submitting a form, but I need alert at time of refreshing.**

Button Code:

```
<form method="post" action="qform.php?srn=<?php echo $srn ?>&id=<?php echo $id ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="quizsb_f">
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn-submit"  id="quizsb">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @MarkCooper I am not getting any answer related to my question from there!

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer

Comment: @MarkCooper I tried the accepted answer too, but it is still alerting, see my updated question.

Comment: Use jQuery to bind the initial event as well.

Comment: @MarkCooper Somehow like this?: `jQuery('#quizsb_f').submit(function() {
   $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});` ?